# Task :react-native-splash-screen:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, detox

command i'm trying to run:

`./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug`

Most of the progress works without failure, but near 90% I get an error message

Error Message:

```
Task :react-native-splash-screen:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
[androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0] /Users/devingantt/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8513b8b73b7884b15d157c479782c91b/transformed/vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Package name 'androidx.vectordrawable' used in: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.
/Users/devingantt/Documents/pqaa_detox/node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest1586857056775225339.xml:5:5-74 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.68.2] /Users/devingantt/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/20ecbe39ea883ff454b9d4682071f45b/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.68.2/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-splash-screen:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.40' // (check what the latest version is!)
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the error message as my minSdkVersion is 21 which should be higher than the 16 that appears. Doing a search in the repo for "16" doesn't appear to help either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution on github https://github.com/uxcam/react-native-ux-cam/issues/24#issuecomment-892547229 adding this to build.gradle seems to fix the problem

```
subprojects { 
    ...

    afterEvaluate { subproject ->
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                defaultConfig {
                    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
                    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```